# Как лучше передавать данные для POST запроса в REST, В URL'е или в JSON'е?

Tags: asp.net-core, rest

Я делаю REST API на ASP.NET Core. Как лучше реализовать передачу данных для POST-запросов? Сейчас у меня все данные для POST-запросов передаётся через JSON, типа так:
 `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"Name": "Онлайн-кошелёк"}' localhost:5029/paymentmethod/create`
Может мне через URL передавать? Я не могу найти в интернете преимущества того и другого подходов.

Comment: Если по фен-шую,  то данные для запроса типа POST,  принято передавать в [теле](https://youtu.be/M0Zybh6zr2Y?si=ZRLCTC5LUTKax5c9&t=65) запроса, а не в заголовке. И кроме того,  если для приложения важна SEO,  то перегружать URL, всякими кракозябрами это не правильно.